# Sharepoint 2013 & news feed

Tags: 2013, newsfeed

Is there any way of disabling the news feed or prevent users adding content into it? unfortunately, just hiding isn't good enough

Comment: just hiding is *not good enough?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the following site features:

"Following Content"
"Site Feed"

Comment: this works for me